# sort a column of an excel report in python

Tags: python, list, odoo

I would like to see if you can help me.
I need to sort a list of a report, first by date and then by folio the problem is that when I try to sort by the second option (folio) it leaves them out of order.
currently order them like this.

original order
[original order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TenLo.jpg)

how it should look
[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dy2Y.jpg)

I order it from an array in python in asc, but the second reference orders it only as shown in the screenshot (image 1)

order='date asc, reference asc'

Comment: Why don't you use pandas for sorting?

Comment: If you want to sort by folio within date, sometimes it works to do the secondary sort first, and then do a second sort by the primary sort variable.

Comment: It seems that you are ordering strings while you would like to order integers. Have you tried to convert your reference asc to integer ?

Comment: This is MarcZ, I want to order but I don't know how I could convert 'reference' to int and order them. since i'm new to this